# Receiving an Error for creating IOS hybrid application from a visualforce page

Tags: authentication, ios, hybrid

I try to create an IOS hybrid_remote application from a visualforce page, but when I run it, I 
receive the following error message:

```
error=invalid_client_id&error_description=client%20identifier%20invalid
```

I'm am using a company sandbox account, so if there are any properties that ruin it, 
or when I create the application with the ForceIos, and when I asked to hand the company's and
organization's name, do I suppose to write something very specific that appears in the developer account?

**Edit**

I enables the OAuth Settings, and [I uploded a picture of how I creating the connected app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWqI4.png)
If i doing something wrong (since its a Sandbox), or I should take more actions elsewhere, then Please let me know.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Sandboxes don't run in the same context as production, so you'll need a Connected App identified on a Sandbox org and use those keys for OAuth.

Comment: Hi, I edit my original post with a photo of how I create the connected app. please take a look at it and tell me what is wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: So for a sandbox - 1) the Connected App needs to be defined on a Sandbox org and 2) the login for the app needs to be point to test / sandbox